# Internal page link is not working in mobile browser

Tags: css, hyperlink, internal-link

```
<a href="#about">About us</a>
....
<div id="about"> Thank you </div>
```

This internal link is working on desktop view. Obviously.
But when it comes to mobile view, link is not working.

Is it touch issue or any other?

Comment: They should work. I guess the problem is somewhere else. Could be a CSS issue in your mobile view or do you use the same id multiple times perhaps? It's hard to tell without a working example. Can you maybe recreate the issue in a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="about"> Thank you </div>
```

ID as you have used is the newest way and supported by HTML 5 and latest browsers. Your mobile device may not support it as it it is not supporting the latest method

The old method is using name attribute as

```
 <a name="C4">Chapter 4</a>
```

But this is not supported by html5

So its better to use both together. Not tried. but will work for you.

```
<a name="C4" id="C4">Chapter 4</a>
```